# Can someone explain how Laravel relationships work?

Tags: php, laravel

When I save a post it saves id of user which posted it.
That is great but I don't understand how.

## Post controller

```
<?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Post;

   class PostController extends Controller
   {
      public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
      {

        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save($post); //i cant understand this line
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
      }
   }

?>
```

## User model

```
<?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
   {
      use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

      public function posts()
      {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Post'); // ?
      }
   }
```

## Post model

```
<?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Post extends Model
  {
    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); // ?
    }
 }
```

I don't understand how belongs to and has many relations work.
If someone could explain it to me I would be very grateful.

Comment: The docs are really extensive. Did you read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 3):

- In this case, the `hasMany` indicates that it will find `many` rows with `the user id` on the `user_id` column in the `posts` table.
- The `belongsTo` simply means that it will find a `user` with an `id` in the `users` table that matches the `user_id` column on the `posts related row`.

Finally, `$request->user()->posts()->save($post);`:

- Get the request
- Get the user from the request
- Get the posts from the user

The `->save($model)` is a bit tricker. This requires that the object passed to the `->save($object)` function is an instance of the relationship. In our case, the relationship is `posts()` and therefore the `$post` simply has to be an instance of `App\Post` (or wherever your `Models` namespace is).

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) and in the chapter "[Eloquent Relationships](https://daylerees.com/codebright-eloquent-relationships/)" from the book "[Code Smart](https://leanpub.com/codesmart)" (Laravel 4).

You can find a lot more resources [in Google](https://www.google.com/#q=laravel+relationships).